# Ember.js - How to properly call the store from a controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

so I am trying to access the store from a controller like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  emailAddress: '',
  message: '',

  isValidEmail: Ember.computed.match('emailAddress', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
  isMessageLongEnough: Ember.computed.gte('message.length', 10),

  isValid: Ember.computed.and('isValidEmail', 'isMessageLongEnough'),
  isNotValid: Ember.computed.not('isValid'),

  actions: {

    sendConfirmation() {
      this.store.createRecord('contact', {
        email: emailAddress,
        message: message,
      }).save();

      this.set('responseMessage', 'We got your message and we will be in contact soon :)');
      this.set('emailAddress', '');
      this.set('message', '');
    }
  }

});
```

I looked at the documentation for Ember.js 2.7 and it doesn't specifically tell you where one can have access to the store, but I know it can be access it through a controller or route.

However, doing it this way gives me these errors:

```
controllers/contact.js: line 17, col 16, 'emailAddress' is not defined.
controllers/contact.js: line 18, col 18, 'message' is not defined.
```

I'm not sure if it's the way I am accessing the controller, or the way I defined emailAddress and message.

Please help and thank you!

SOLVED:
For this part:

```
sendConfirmation() {
    this.store.createRecord('contact', {
    email: emailAddress,
    message: message,
 }).save();
```

It should have been this:

```
sendConfirmation() {
    this.store.createRecord('contact', {
    email: this.get('emailAddress'),
    message: this.get('message'),
  }).save();
```

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `store` will be injected into `controller` and `route`. and one more thing you should get properties through `get`

```
sendConfirmation() {
    var newRecordObj = {};
    newRecordObj['email'] = this.get('emailAddress');
    newRecordObj['message'] = this.get('message');

    this.get('store').createRecord('contact', newRecordObj).save((result) => {
        //success handling 
        this.set('responseMessage', 'We got your message and we will be in contact soon :)');
        this.set('emailAddress', '');
        this.set('message', '');
    }, () => {
        //error handling
        this.set('responseMessage', 'Error message');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the way you access the store, it's that you're trying to add a contact with an email and a message without actually defining the variables.

```
sendConfirmation() {
  this.store.createRecord('contact', {
    // what do you expect emailAddress and message values to be at this point?
    email: emailAddress, // <-- emailAddress is not defined
    message: message,    // <-- message is not defined
  }).save();
  // ...
```

Did you perhaps mean to retrieve them first?

```
sendConfirmation() {
  // retrieve emailAddress and message first
  const { 
    emailAddress, 
    message 
  } = this.getProperties('emailAddress', 'message');

  // then use them to create a contact
  this.store.createRecord('contact', {
    email: emailAddress
    message: message
  }).save();
  // ...
```

One more thing, accessing the store should probably be done using `this.get('store')`, since using getters/setters is the ember-way of accessing/manipulating properties.